# php function return empty json string

Tags: php, json, ajax

I have a php function which inserts form data into multiple tables. I want to return 'true' to the JSON response. This is the code which i have tried but it returns the empty string. Why is it so? Any suggestions?

**code**

```
function insertStores($params)
{
    $img = $_FILES['sm_image']['name'];
    $chk=mysqli_query($this->conn,"select * from store_manufacture where sm_brand_name='".$params['sm_name']."'");
    if(mysqli_num_rows($chk)==0) {
        $query = "INSERT INTO store_manufacture (sm_brand_name,sm_image, sm_link, sm_description,sm_display) VALUES('" . $params["sm_name"] . "','" . $img . "', '" . $params["sm_link"] . "','" . $params["sm_desc"] . "','" . $params["sm_switch"] . "');  ";

        $result = mysqli_query($this->conn, $query);
        if ($result) {
            $store_id = mysqli_insert_id($this->conn);
            foreach ($params['categories_chk'] as $cat_id => $name) {
                $query2 = "insert into store_category values ('',$store_id,$cat_id)";
                $result2 = mysqli_query($this->conn, $query2);
                $sourcePath = $_FILES['sm_image']['tmp_name']; 
                $targetPath = "images/" . $img; 
                move_uploaded_file($sourcePath, $targetPath); 
            }
        }
        echo json_encode($result);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not a JSON/JS expert but I think you want to return string `true` or `false`.

Comment: It doesn't echo anything if the `SELECT` returns >0 rows.

Comment: What is it supposed to echo if the row was already in the table so there's nothing to insert?

Comment: `$result` will only return false if query fails, does not return true. Also, as @AbraCadaver mentions, you need to return type of string not bool.

Comment: In the `if ($result)` you can just do `echo json_encode('true')` in the else do the same for false.

Comment: @bos570: INSERT will return `true` if successful _Returns FALSE on failure. For successful SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE or EXPLAIN queries mysqli_query() will return a mysqli_result object. For other successful queries mysqli_query() will return TRUE._

Comment: @AbraCadaver doesn't INSERT return the number of row affected. So, while the condition might hold true it doest return boolean true if success?

Comment: @AbraCadaver nvm you are right. Thanks for clarifying!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got a couple of problems.

`$result` is not a boolean but rather a query result object.  It is only a boolean if the result failed, in which case it will be false.  However, if your query is successful, it will be a query result object, and you cannot convert that into json.  Moreover, even if it was a boolean, you still don't want to convert it to json, nor do you want to follow some of the suggestions that effectively have you return a literal string of `true` or `false`.

The reason is because even though json_encoding a boolean:

`echo json_encode( true );`

Is allowed by PHP, it will return this:

`true`

Which is not valid JSON.  Most client-side libraries, when told to expect JSON, will throw an error if they encounter a non-JSON result.  This is not JSON.  Instead you need to come up with some valid JSON to return.  It can even be something simple like this (manually buildin:

`return json_encode( [ 'success' => $result ? true : false ] )`

Which will result an a valid JSON document of one of:

```
{ "success": true }
```

or

```
{ "success": false }
```

Then adjust your client library to search the `success` key of the returned JSON document.

Also, you should **really** be using prepared parameters.  I would guess that your chances of SQL Injection vulnerabilities are high here.

Answer (score -1):

I think that you must be passed to `json_encode` an array such as `'a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3, 'd' => 4, 'e' => 5`. 
Your query is `INSERT` that return `True` or `False`. 
You can try to format an array such as:

```
$result = array ("result"=> $result) 
json_encode($result)
```

Comment: `$result` isn't true or false.  It is false or a result object, which cannot be json encoded.